# Matlab Automatic Nuclei Count stacks

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am using this borrowed code to automatically count DAPI stained nuclei.

```
Hs.dirPath = pwd;
[Hs.dataFiles,Hs.dataNums] = getDataFiles(Hs.dirPath);
[Hs.foundChannels,Hs.fileNums,Hs.imgExts] = getImageFiles(Hs.dirPath);
for i = 1:length(Hs.fileNums)
    
    Hs.fileNum = Hs.fileNums(i);    
    fileName = ['dapi' sprintf('%03d',Hs.fileNum) '.tif'];    
    Hs.DI = readmm(fileName);
    Hs.DI = Hs.DI.imagedata;
    Hs.DI = scale(max(Hs.DI(:,:,round(linspace(10,size(Hs.DI,10),50))),[],3));
    binDapi = Hs.DI>adaptthresh(Hs.DI);

                masktmp = imclearborder(binDapi | ~Hs.DI);
                masktmp = bwareaopen(masktmp,50); 
                if any(masktmp(:))
                    binDapi = masktmp;
                end
                
    L = bwlabel(binDapi);
    numObjects = max(L,[],1:2);
    Hs.currObjs = [];
    Hs.allMasks = [];
    for j = 1:numObjects
        fnumStr = sprintf('%03d',Hs.fileNum);
        objMask = L == j;
        newObj = improc2.buildImageObject(objMask, fnumStr, Hs.dirPath);

        Hs.currObjs = [Hs.currObjs, newObj];
        Hs.allMasks = cat(3,Hs.allMasks,objMask);
    end

    objects = Hs.currObjs;
    save(sprintf('%s%sdata%03d.mat',Hs.dirPath,filesep,Hs.fileNum),'objects');
    [Hs.dataFiles,Hs.dataNums] = getDataFiles(Hs.dirPath);
    clear objects;
    Hs.currObjs = [];
end
```

It ends up fusing nuclei that are on different planes. In the image shown here there should be 14 nuclei but 1 and 6, 2 and 5 and 3 and 7 end up being counted as the same.

I have tried changing the threshold etc. but it does not help with the stacks.

Any suggestions to modify the code? Thanks. [Matlab output left, manually counted nuclei right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SGCB.png)

[Here is the av intensity projection of the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okqii.jpg)

Comment: If you post the original image we may be able to help you come up with a new image processing technique. The image mask being formed by the adaptive threshold algorithm `adaptthresh` doesn't seem capable of forming the mask you desire. If it were me, I would experiment with `imsegkmeans`.

Comment: Thanks. I added the projection of the original image (tif stacks are too big to upload). I will try imsegkmeans. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought MATLAB's `imfindcircles` might be useful here. It overcounts #14, but seems to do better than what you have right now.

```
img = imread('Okqii.jpg');

mask = imbinarize(img,'adaptive');

cc = bwconncomp(mask);
lm = labelmatrix(cc);

imshow(img), hold on

for idx = 1:cc.NumObjects
  [c,r] = imfindcircles(lm == idx, [15,100], 'ObjectPolarity','bright');
  viscircles(c,r,'Color','b');
end
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is cool and I will play around with it. It doesn't seem to work with the tif stack - any thoughts on that? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm honestly not familiar with tiff stacks or how they work. Without a tiff stack to experiment with myself, I'm afraid I can be of no help.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to compress a tiff stack so I can upload it, but am coming up blank.